# SQL Server return data from second table if value in column in first table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables

Both tables I have the following columns

```
Type, Name, Description, Code
```

If the value in the **Code** field in Table1 > 0 then the **Name** and **Description** fields are blank and I need to get the **Name** and **Description** from Table2 where the Code from Table1 and Table2 are equal.

How do I write a query to return one row so that I get the following

```
T1Type, T1Name, T1Description, T1Code if code = 0

T1Type, T2Name, T2Description, T2Code if code > 0
```

Apologies that I havent formatted it into a table layout but I am not sure how to do it.

TIA

Comment: You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to do the job. Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos had tried the left join and but was struggling with/not sure about coalesce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `COALSECE` your values so it takes the values where they are not null.

`COALSECE` works that way it looks at the first column, and if that is NULL then it takes the values from the second column etc.etc.etc.

```
Select t1.Type, COALESCE(t1.[Name],t2.[Name]) as Name, COALESCE(t1.[Description],t2.[Description]) as Description, t1.Code from Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code
```